# MacOS crashes when opening Flutter app on Xcode Simulator

Tags: xcode, flutter, macos, android-studio, ios-simulator

I am creating a Flutter app in Android Studio and have installed my app on the Xcode iOS Simulator. Whenever I open the app, the Simulator's screen turns white for about one second before my Mac completely freezes and forces a restart, saying "Your computer restarted because of a problem."

When I emulate my app in the Android Studio Android Emulator (Pixel 6 API 33), the app functions perfectly fine. I have tried restarting Xcode, Xcode Simulator, Android Studio and MacOS, but the problem still persists.

MacOS Monterey 12.5.1,
Simulator: iPhone 14 Pro, iOS 16.0

What could be causing this and how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you able to see any errors or messages prior to crash? Without code or error messages it'll be hard to help.

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i can not help without an error message but try to run the app in release mode.

```
flutter run --release
```